# Removing last ng-form from validation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a master detail form in angularjs. The form is typical transactions form with some master data like Name, type etc. The detail part contains many lines (can be added and deleted). Each line has input fields for Credit, Debit and Account Number. I have been able to add the required validations both on master portion of the form and detailed portion as well using `ng-form` directive. My form looks like following
[image]

you can see that I already have `Add Row` button that will add row on detail portion. Now I have strange requirement that is to add a row automatically when user is entering data in last row. I have even done that using `ng-focus` directive but the next part of requirement is to remove the last row from validation context if it is not used (not dirty) and successfully submit the remaining form. How can I do it in angular. Please find the [Code on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XvPKVYFBM8NWa8DITmXx?p=preview) and guide me how I can remove last row of detailed portion from validation context if it is not dirty.

Answer (score 1):

`ngRepeat` sets `$last` to true for the last row. So you can just disable `ng-require` if an input is on the last row.

You could do something like `data-ng-required="!entry.DebitAmoun && !$last"` and similar for each input.

The above will work if you assume that last row always contains empty input fields. Whenever the user adds any value on the last row, then a new row is created.

Comment: I want the last row to be removed if it is invalid and not dirty and also remove its effect from overall form validation

Comment: Your answer will allow the user to make last row dirty and have invalid values in the last row