# ng-form not available after manually deleting an item from collection of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

**Edit** Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVxMUYgH70m7a0VWov98?p=preview) for this question

I have a master detail form for an accounting transaction. The master portion just contains two fields name and Type. The detail portion can have two or more entries and each entry has AccountId, Debit and Credit fields. The form looks like
[image]
You can see that there is a delete button against each entry so if we have more than two entries we can delete any entry at random. The form html looks like following

```
<body data-ng-app="transactions">
    <div data-ng-controller="transactionsController">
        <form role="form" name="transactionForm" novalidate data-ng-submit="create()">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2 class="form-login-heading">Create Transaction</h2>
                    <div data-ng-repeat="error in errors" class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{error[0]}}
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" data-ng-model="transaction.Name" required autofocus>
                    <div>
                        <span class="error" data-ng-show="transactionForm.name.$error.required && submitted">Please enter Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control" placeholder="Type" data-ng-model="transaction.Type" required>
                    <div>
                        <span class="error" data-ng-show="transactionForm.type.$error.required && submitted">Please enter Type</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--<input type="text" readonly name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number" data-ng-model="transaction.Number">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="transaction.IsFinalized" /> <label>Finalize</label>-->


                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Account</th>
                            <th>Debit</th>
                            <th>Credit</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-ng-form="entryForm" data-ng-repeat="entry in transaction.Entries track by $index">
                            <td>
                                <input required name="accountId" data-ng-model="entry.AccountId" class="form-control" />
                                <span class="error" data-ng-show="entryForm.accountId.$error.required && submitted">Please select an account</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="debit" data-ng-required="!entry.CreditAmount" class="form-control" placeholder="Debit" data-ng-model="entry.DebitAmount">
                                <span class="error" data-ng-show="entryForm.debit.$error.required && submitted">Debit is required</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" data-ng-focus="checkAddRow($index)" name="credit" data-ng-required="!entry.DebitAmount" class="form-control" placeholder="Credit" data-ng-model="entry.CreditAmount">
                                <span class="error" data-ng-show="entryForm.credit.$error.required && submitted">Credit is required</span>
                            </td>
                            <td><button data-ng-show="transaction.Entries.length>2" class="btn btn-md btn-info " type="button" data-ng-click="deleteRow($index)">delete</button></td>




                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total</td>
                            <td><input readonly name="totalDebit" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Debit" data-ng-value="totalDebit()"></td>
                            <td><input readonly name="totalCredit" compare-to="totalDebit" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Credit" data-ng-value="totalCredit()"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><b>Difference</b></td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="difference" readonly type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-value="difference()">
                                <!--<span class="error" data-ng-show="submitted && !differencezero">Difference should be 0</span>-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br />
                    <button class="btn btn-md btn-info" type="submit">Create</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-md btn-info" data-ng-show="transaction.Entries.length<15" type="button" data-ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
                    <div data-ng-hide="message == ''" class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{message}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>

        <pre>{{transactionForm.entryForm|json}}</pre>
    </div>
```

I have the requirement that when focus is on Credit input of last entry the new entry should automatically added to the UI. I do it by using `addRow` and `checkAddRow` method on my controller. these methods are as follows

```
$scope.checkAddRow = function (index) {
                if (index == $scope.transaction.Entries.length - 1) {
                    $scope.addRow();
                }
            }

            $scope.addRow = function () {
                entry = {
                    EntryTime: '',
                    DebitAmount: '',
                    CreditAmount: '',
                    AccountId: ''
                };
                $scope.transaction.Entries.push(entry);
                console.log($scope.transactionForm);
            }

            $scope.deleteRow = function (index) {
                $scope.transaction.Entries.splice(index, 1);
                console.log($scope.transactionForm);
            }
```

Again this part is just fine and works well. But I have another requirement that says that if last entry is not used it should not cause the form to invalidate. It should rather be removed from `transaction.Entries` collection and rest of the data should be saved normally. To achieve this, I have `create` function defined on `$scope` that looks like following

```
$scope.create = function () {
                $scope.submitted = true;
                if ($scope.transactionForm.entryForm && $scope.transactionForm.entryForm.$invalid && $scope.transactionForm.entryForm.$pristine) {

                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.deleteRow($scope.transaction.Entries.length - 1);
                    });

                    $timeout(function () {
                        console.log('From time out', $scope.transactionForm.$valid);
                        console.log($scope.transactionForm.$valid);
                        if (!$scope.transactionForm.$valid) return;

                        alert('data saved!');
                        console.log($scope.transactionForm);
                        //$scope.transactionForm.name.focus();
                    }, 200);

                }
                else {
                    if ($scope.transactionForm.$valid) {
                        alert('data saved 2');
                    }
                }

            }
```

You can see that what `create` function is doing. It is checking if `entryForm (ng-form)` is present in the main form (`transactionForm`) then it checks if `entryForm` is `$invalid` and `$pristine` if all these flags are true then, I delete the last entry from `$scope.transaction.Entries` and save the data (currently an alert to show data is saved) after `$timeout`. If I don't use timeout then the form is invalid so I have to wait for 200ms before I check the forms `$valid` flag after removing last row. But to my surprise when I remove last row from create function, there is no `entryForm` attached to the outer `transactionForm`. On the other hand If I delete entries using delete buttons present on UI, the `entryForm` is present inside the main `transactionForm`. Can anyone explain why is that. I have added `<pre>{{transactionForm|json}}</pre>` at the end to see when it is and when it is not available on main form. I have created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVxMUYgH70m7a0VWov98?p=preview) to show what I mean. just add some data in two input fields of the master portion, enter some data in accountid field of both entries, when you reach the Credit input of second (last) entry, a new entry will be automatically added. Ignore that row and just push create button. The last entry will be removed and data will save but the `entryForm` will not be there anymore. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How is this different than your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594189/removing-last-ng-form-from-validation-in-angularjs)?

Comment: In previous question, I did not figure out the behavior of `ng-form` when I delete an entry from `create` method

Comment: I think, I will have to create a custom directive and answer to this question may help me in making that directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a problem here is that your definition of whether the form is valid or not depends on the state of the last row.

The last row could be of the following variety:

1. row fetched from the backend, but not new --> should only invalidate if not valid
2. row is new and $pristine --> should not invalidate
3. row is new, but $dirty (and still last) --> should only invalidate if not valid

You are trying to remove the last row and then re-evaluate the form for validity.

Approach it the other way - don't let the last row invalidate the form if it's in `$pristine` state:

Here's a simplified example:

```
<form name="transactionForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
  <table>    
    <tr ng-form="entryForm" ng-repeat="transaction in transactions">

      <td><input ng-model="transaction.account" 
                 ng-required="transaction !== newLastEntry || entryForm.$dirty"></td>

      <td><input ng-model="transaction.amount" 
                 ng-required="transaction !== newLastEntry || entryForm.$dirty"
                 ng-focus="addEntryIfLast($last)" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Note `$scope.newLastEntry` here. It is set to the new empty (and last) entry. This happens when you add a new empty row:

```
function addEmptyEntry(){
  $scope.newLastEntry = {};
  $scope.transactions.push($scope.newLastEntry);
}
```

And so, `ng-required` is applied only if row is NOT new last OR otherwise `$dirty`.

Then, on submit, you can remove the last entry if it's in `$pristine` state and indeed the new last (as opposed to whatever existed before):

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  var itemsToSubmit = angular.copy($scope.transactions);

  if ($scope.transactionForm.$invalid) return;

  if ($scope.transactionForm.entryForm && 
      $scope.transactionForm.entryForm.$pristine && 
      $scope.transactions[$scope.transactions.length - 1] === $scope.newLastEntry) {

    itemsToSubmit.splice(itemsToSubmit.length - 1);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(itemsToSubmit));
};
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hgMIjsV1qijDHmOGl7dt?p=preview)

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid, did it work for you? It works for me on Chrome and IE

Comment: Yes, it did. thank you. I believe there has to be a better solution for this. Let's assume this as answer since we find a better technique

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid, out of curiosity, what seems hacky, inefficient or inelegant to you? To me, it's the fact that a controller "knows about `transactionForm` and `entryForm`, even though those were defined by the View.

Comment: Maybe this is the super solution. As I am new to angular world and my so far study suggests that the logic belongs to a directive not to controller. That's all I can say about it until I have more knowledge about the subject in hand

Comment: I have created a fork on your plunk at http://plnkr.co/edit/yjnTaQBYHKic00mjKOmf?p=preview. The problem is now that when I delete last row using delete button the entryForm in undefined and all the validation that is based on entryForm is broken. can you please have a look at this?

Comment: Either I don't understand your comment or I can't reproduce what you are describing with your fork. What is "all the validation that is based on `entryForm`"?

Comment: please focus the credit textbox in last row, it will add new row. do this twice and you will have two empty rows added at the bottom. Then delete the last row using delete button I created. It will delete last row and we will also loose reference to `entryForm`. it will give undefined after that unless we add another row

Comment: Why is this a problem? This is a valid case. You could avoid it if you named entry forms differently, but I don't why it's required.